# How to bind Datatable button to Server side With URL

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to export the data on server side and then download it. Right now I use Datatable Framework. I am trying to do something like this.

```
buttons: [ 'excel',
           {
             "extend": "excel",
             "text": "TestServerSide", 
             "url": "./GenerateExcel"
           }
]
```

But it doesn't work. My goal is to bind my datatable dom button to server side.

Comment: "_export the data on server side and then download it_" Does not compute :) What does "export the data on server side" mean?

Comment: I meant Making export code on server side.

Comment: Perhaps it is something like this you are looking for? -> **https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/plug-ins#download**